# unable to play video when app rebuild swift

Tags: swift, avplayer, avcapturesession

video not playing  when app rebuild  (file path url saving into coreData) using AVCaptureSession

filepath not changing before and after rebuild.

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3DA93FBC-9A20-40B4-A017-B3D5C7768301/tmp/63F6CEED-3202-4F5F-999B-5F138D73635D.mp4

i did all the ways, nothing works

here my code for record the video

```
  func setupPreview() {
        // Configure previewLayer
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
       previewLayer?.frame = shapeLayer.bounds
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    shapeLayer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    }
func setupSession() -> Bool {
   
       captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
   
       // Setup Camera
       let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)!
   
       do {
       
           let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
       
           if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
               captureSession.addInput(input)
               activeInput = input
           }
       } catch {
           print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
           return false
       }
   
       // Setup Microphone
       let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!
   
       do {
           let micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone)
           if captureSession.canAddInput(micInput) {
               captureSession.addInput(micInput)
           }
       } catch {
           print("Error setting device audio input: \(error)")
           return false
       }
   
   
       // Movie output
       if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
           captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
       }
   
       return true
   }

func startSession() {
   
       if !captureSession.isRunning {
        videoQueue().async {
               self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
       }
   }
func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }
func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
        return DispatchQueue.main
    }
func currentVideoOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
        var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation
    
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            case .portrait:
                orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            case .landscapeRight:
                orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
            default:
                 orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
         }
    
         return orientation
     }
func startRecording() {
 
     if movieOutput.isRecording == false {
        save.setTitle("stop", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        
         let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)
     
         if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
             connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
         }
     
         if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
             connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
         }
     
         let device = activeInput.device
     
         if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {
         
             do {
                 try device.lockForConfiguration()
                 device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                 device.unlockForConfiguration()
             } catch {
                print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
             }
         
         }
     
         //EDIT2: And I forgot this
         outputURL = tempURL()
         movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
     
         }
         else {
            
             stopRecording()
         }
 
    }

func tempURL() -> URL? {
  
    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
 let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
    path22 = path
    
    let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let folderPath: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloads", isDirectory: true)
    let fileURL: URL = folderPath.appendingPathComponent(path)
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
 
}
```

func stopRecording() {

```
    if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
        movieOutput.stopRecording()
        
     }
}
```

here saving into coredata

```
    let managedObject = self.managedObjectContext
  entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MediaData", in: managedObject!)
      let personMO = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObject)
     
       personMO.setValue("\(self.videoURL!)", forKey: "videosS")
      personMO.setValue(dataImage, forKey: "thumbnails")
      print(personMO)
      do
      {
       try managedObject?.save()
          print("video saved")
      }
      catch
      {
          print("Catch Erroe : Failed To
```

}

let appdel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdel.avplayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
print(videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: appdel.avplayer)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
appdel.avplayer?.play()

Answer (score 1):

You must *never* save a full filepath into CoreData or anywhere else. File paths are not persistent. Your app is *sandboxed*. The sandbox path can change at any time, especially between launches and installations.

Instead, save the file *name* and *reconstruct* the path each time you need it. Just as you are calling `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory...)` to construct the file path initially, so you must call it *every* time you want to access this file.

Comment: yes , did same as you said , when i call below function every time file name changing.. but even video not playing

Comment: func playVideo() { let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
     let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")   
        let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let folderPath: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloads", isDirectory: true) ,let fileURL: URL = folderPath.appendingPathComponent(path)
        print("file path of the url is ", URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) 
        avplayer = AVPlayer(url:URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

Comment: let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avplayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds, self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer) avplayer.play()
    }

Comment: Well, you're not going to play a video directly out of the temp folder.